# "Sec value dont match" - When trying to login into wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Has anyone "Sec value dont match" - When trying to login into WordPress after entering the correct password?

I have tried resolving this issue with the following:

- Re-installing WordPress
- Updating the PHP version to 7.2
- Resetting the Htaccess
- Resetting WordPress SALTs
- Turning off Plugins and themes

[Screenshot of the error on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHS7e.jpg)

[Link to a video of the issue](https://gyazo.com/a23d809274ac34ef6ca411b48c1ccd66)

Comment: Firstly, welcome to StackOverflow!
Secondly, are you absolutely sure that _a)_ you're using WordPress as downloaded from WordPress.org and _b)_ that this is the exact error you're seeing (with spelling errors and all)? It's just because I did a deep search on an up-to-date installation (with lots of plugins...) and I couldn't see that error anywhere in the source code for the latest stable version of WordPress (I've also checked [here](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop) for a development version). So I guess this can't be coming from a 'normal' WP installation? What is your OS?

Comment: Hi there. We are using a version of WordPress from Wordpress.org. That is the exact phrase I see when logging into the site. I found the same when looking through the files on the site too, including dragging down what's on the current site and searching those files also in case it might of been tampered with. I'm viewing the site on Windows 10 and getting error on Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't got good news for you. After an even deeper session of intense googling, I have spotted the culprit: one of your plugins (or possibly even a core WordPress file) has been compromised with what is known as the `sasdk123` backdoor. Since you mention that you've downloaded WordPress directly from WordPress.org, I can only assume that you got a plugin and/or a theme that had this backdoor.

You mentioned PHP 7.2 and using `.htaccess` files — which, I presume, shows that you're using Apache — but not the operating system you're using for providing web service. *If* you're running Linux/FreeBSD/macOS, then you ought to do the following:

- Go to the document root of your website (where you have installed WordPress)
- Recursively search for that phrase using `grep "Sec value dont match" -R *`
- Eventually, it will hit the infected file (or files), and you should immediately remove it
- If that file belongs to a specific plugin/theme, just remove the whole plugin/theme; it's most likely compromised, and there is always a possibility that it tries to 'heal itself' by remotely downloading a new copy of itself; if you still cannot login, use the [WordPress Command Line Tool](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/), which should allow you to selectively disable and enable plugins and themes from the shell
- If you can't do that for some reason (e.g. because you have no permission to run commands on the remote server) but have access to SFTP or web-based FTP or something similar, then go to the `wp-content/plugins` folder, make a copy of each plugin inside, then delete them, one by one, until you are able to login; if you still can't login, then do the same with the themes (you will need at least *one* theme, or WordPress won't work; you can always stick to one of the official default themes, such as [`twentytwentyone`](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwentyone/); if it's not installed, then you can download it from the WordPress Library (just follow that link) and then upload it to the `wp-content/themes` folder
- After you have done all the above, you should still have all your content (including users and their passwords) but lack some functionality (depending on which plugin(s) or theme(s) were infected). That's ok. Before you install everything back again — and do it from `wordpress.org`! — do yourself a favour and install one security plugin. Everybody has their favourite, but I personally recommend [Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/). Since you're using Apache, my second choice would be [BulletProof Security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulletproof-security/). There are more (some people swear by Sucuri, for example), but I really just have used these two, so I can't personally recommend anything else.

Wordfence works straight out of the box (you can fine-tune its configuration later) and even the free version will do a *lot* to clean up your overall WordPress configuration; it also features a powerful web firewall to block incoming attacks, as well as many other features. For instance, I use it to provide Two-Factor Authentication (a must these days), because it's built-in (no need for another plugin!) and free (unlike Jetpack's solution).

On top of all that, the Wordfence team has earned some reputation in the field of web security. They actively keep in touch with other security teams  (such as WordPress's own; Google; Cloudflare; and others...) and exchange their forensic data — and then write extensive reports on their corporate blog. It's thanks to it that I *finally* figured out *what* kind of backdoor this is.

Ironically, what caught my attention was the *spelling mistake* (`dont` as opposed to `don't`). The WordPress translation team would hardly let something so obvious pass; granted, it *could* be a message from a third-party plugin and not from the core code; but, in any case, it ought to be much easier to search on Google for any message inside any of the themes, plugins, or the core; after all, such messages are not only on public servers, but they are also available for translation (on the [WordPress Translate](https://translate.wordpress.org/) page, formerly known as Glotpress).

So the only reasonable explanation was that this was a message coming from either

- a paid-for plugin/theme, which might *not* be listed publicly on the WP Library (and as such it wouldn't have been crawled by Google)
- your own in-house development (in which case you ought to know where the message comes from!)
- **someone hacked your WP installation** ⚠️

Well, unfortunately, that seems to be the case

You're not the first person that found that error message when attempting to plugin; in fact, on the support forum for Wordfence, two years ago, that error message comes up on [this thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/backdoorphp-sasdk123-4871-info/).

Because Wordfence labelled that backdoor with the code name `PHP/sasdk123.4871`, it means that security experts had encountered this backdoor before. We can now trace it back to 2017 when a [Wordfence report](https://www.wordfence.com/blog/2017/12/backdoor-captcha-plugin/) talked about a backdoor appearing on a plugin known as WordPress Captcha. There is a quite dark story behind it, and the Wordfence team got deep into it with gusto — it reads like a cyberpunk detective novel, and is even scarier and darker because, well, it happened (is happening!) in the real world. [Bleeping Computer](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/backdoor-found-in-wordpress-plugin-with-more-than-300-000-installations/) also picked up the story and followed it up.

This backdoor affected at least 300,000 WordPress installations; fortunately, in *most* cases, there weren't any dangerous side effects, and most people weren't even aware that they had this backdoor in their system. It doesn't slow the system down; it's not taking precious CPU time or memory or disk space (it's not mining cryptocurrencies!). The results were not illegal (i.e. it didn't start posting child porn or act as a gateway for pirated software/music/videos). As a result, it was not easy to detect.

The purpose of the backdoor was much more nefarious, and not immediately obvious. And, as it happens so often, it was found by pure luck.

Somewhen back in 2017, someone at the WordPress core team flagged the WordPress Captcha plugin because it was infringing Automattic's trademark, 'WordPress'. In other words, if you name a plugin 'WordPress Something', you're attempting to benefit from the positive image of Automattic's brand by implying that your plugin is somehow endorsed/approved by them. Of course, that wasn't the case, so they flagged it for review, meaning mostly that the plugin owner very likely got a warning to change the plugin name immediately or risk getting removed from the official WordPress Library. Apparently, there was no 'immediate' response, since Automattic did, indeed, remove the plugin.

There are many reasons for plugins to be removed, most of which have to do with plugins being abandoned by their original creators — and this means such plugins are *not* being updated/upgraded and *may* have security flaws, which nobody bothered to correct. That's one of the main reasons for *not* using 'abandoned' projects, even if they are completely harmless — or were, at the time they were written. Who knows what security flaws may have been found since then?

When a plugin or theme gets removed by Automattic, the Wordfence team gets a notification. They will put that plugin/theme on their list of 'abandoned plugins/themes' so as to warn their users. Because many plugins *may* have been removed because of security flaws, they also tend to inspect their code in more detail (to learn about how the exploit works and build new security countermeasures against it). In this case, however, the reason for removal was 'copyright infringement on the plugin name', so they didn't give much of a thought to this particular plugin.

By sheer chance, though, they *did* audit the code — and what they found was this `sasdk123` backdoor. There [are a few copies of it around](https://gist.github.com/tbouron/fdcfe8ade38a429099d8872a1a1c1635) if you have any interest in comparing it with your infected code. You can clearly see *where* the message appears: right at the beginning, at some sort of function which is trying to figure out if this is a remote attempt by the hacker to log in.

*Why* this particular exploit? Well, you ought to read the 3 or 4 reports done by Wordfence; they didn't limit themselves to examining the *technical* aspects of the hack, but rather — and more interestingly, IMHO — the *social* aspects.

In essence, that hack was designed to inject links on articles and pages of unsuspecting sites — which would be invisible for the site visitors, but *not* for the Google crawler bot, which would therefore increase ranking for those injected links. Now imagine — one plugin, used by 300,000 websites, had been infected with this backdoor. That meant 300,000 websites pointing to the same links. You can imagine how the Google ranking would skyrocket for these links! And that was *not* the *only* plugin that had been infected; there were at least seven others (and possibly more).

And for what? Well, if we can rely on the Wordfence team forensic report, apparently all of this could be traced to a particular individual associated with a shady operation of selling medical drugs online (allegedly even without prescription). This guy would act behind several shell companies legitimately *buying* these high-profile plugins from their original authors and put his backdoor code in them — as those hundreds of thousands of website owners saw the new versions become available for download, they would promptly install the infected code without knowing, and start linking back to the online drug shop — thus boosting its ranking on Google and making it one of the most visible drug shops out there. Obviously, this immense botnet was not used solely to boost the rating of that single website; it is now factually verifiable that there were many customers of this 'ranking booster service', mostly online casinos and similar businesses which usually have a hard time doing legitimate advertising, and have no other choice but to hire such shady businesses as this one.

While eventually the *known* cases of infected plugins were 'fixed' — sometimes Automattic would force-push a patched version of the plugin, sometimes they would simply remove the plugin from the Library and expect website owners to eventually read the warning message — the question remains what *other* plugins/themes *might* still be around, still injecting links into WP-based websites. I've certainly been a victim of one such attack, albeit using a completely different vector of infection — the purpose, however, was the same, adding links to boost their ranking on Google; they were just less careful and didn't 'hide' their links, so, eventually, I figured out which sites had been compromised and cleaned them up. But that didn't happen 'instantly', and, in truth, I have no idea for how long my websites had been boosting the ranking of those semi-legal, shady businesses.

BTW, at the time of writing, the guy behind this 2017 exploit *still* co-owns the company behind the online drugstore. These days, his family (most of which work on the company) are today millionaires, and, although their exploits have been exposed publicly so long ago, they seem to be ignored by the authorities.

What that means for us, WordPress users, is that there is still a malicious hacker at bay, and if he managed to buy plugins in order to infect them and nobody stopped him, then he will do it again and again.

That's why it's so important to get one of those well-known security plugins running on one's webservers — all of them — even at the cost of a slight drop of performance (which might only be noticeable at the backoffice anyway).